# Submit a form variable in a secure way

Tags: html, forms, security, post

I have a page with some forms. Each form does an action on a specific product (i.e. delete product). When a form is submitted, I need to know what product must be deleted, so I've included an hidden input inside forms containing the product ID.

```
<form method="post" action="delete.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
  Product one <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="delete.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" />
  Product two <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Unfortunately, `id` value can be changed via browser inspector.

Is there a secure way to submit a variable inside a form? I've found [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400895/secure-way-of-passing-form-variable), but in my case I have multiple ids so I can't know the submitted value before submission.

Comment: The way to secure this is to revalidate the ID when the delete script receives it by applying the same logic that caused it to be offered as an option for deletion in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In .NET, how do I prevent, or handle, tampering with form data of disabled fields before submission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582879/in-net-how-do-i-prevent-or-handle-tampering-with-form-data-of-disabled-field)

Comment: @AlexK. So you mean, for example, check if id=2 corresponds with a "Product two" label, or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible, all you need to do is to verify in the back end after the submitting process if the submitted $_POST['id'] is valid/available for deletion, if valid, proceed with the deleting process , if not, go back and post a warning/notification saying "Invalid","Can't delete item", or "Why the h**l are you messing up with my code?"

Comment: Ahahaha! +1 for "Why the h**l are you messing up with my code?"